Building layout of the warehouse using react three fiber, while building 1/10 project it started freezing
I am trying to create 3D layout of the warehouse but even I build little part of the project it started freezing in first person movemenent . So I am wonder is that possible to create such a project in R3F or am I not using correct strcuture.
I will provide my some codes.
const generateBoxPositions = () => {
  const positions = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      positions.push([-4 + j * 2, i * 1.5 + 0.5, 0]); // Adjust position
    }
  }
  return positions;
};

const Box = ({ position }) => (
  <mesh position={position}>
    <boxGeometry args={[1.5, 1, 1]} />
    <meshStandardMaterial color="brown" />
  </mesh>
);
const Shelf = ({ position, color }) => (
  <group position={position}>
    <group>
      {[...Array(5)].map((_, i) => (
        <mesh key={i} position={[0, i * 1.5, 0]}>
          <boxGeometry args={[10, 0.1, 2]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
        </mesh>
      ))}
      {[...Array(2)].map((_, i) => (
        <mesh key={i} position={[i === 0 ? -4.8 : 4.8, 3, 0]}>
          <boxGeometry args={[0.2, 7, 2]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial color={color} />
        </mesh>
      ))}
    </group>
    {generateBoxPositions().map((pos, index) => (
      <Box key={index} position={pos} />
    ))}
  </group>
);

export default Shelf;


And I am using this generic shelf in this component
import Shelf from "../Shelf";

export default function Row({ position, color }) {
  return (
    <group position={position}>
      <Shelf position={[0, 0, 0]} color={color} />
      <Shelf position={[0, 0, 2.1]} color={color} />
    </group>
  );
}

And when I finish one row of shelves I am creating rows for one zone
import React from "react";
import Shelf from "../../Generic/Shelf";
import Row from "../../Generic/Row";

export default function S112() {
  return (
    <group>
      <group position={[0, 0, 0]}>
        <Row position={[0, 0, 0]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 8]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 16]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 24]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 32]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 40]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 48]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 56]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 64]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 72]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 80]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 88]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 96]} color={"grey"} />
      </group>
      <group position={[30, 0, 0]}>
        <Row position={[0, 0, 0]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 8]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 16]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 24]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 32]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 40]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 48]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 56]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 64]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 72]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 80]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 88]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 96]} color={"grey"} />
      </group>
      <group position={[45, 0, 0]}>
        <Row position={[0, 0, 0]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 8]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 16]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 24]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 32]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 40]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 48]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 56]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 64]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 72]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 80]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 88]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 96]} color={"grey"} />
      </group>
      <group position={[70, 0, 0]}>
        <Row position={[0, 0, 0]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 8]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 16]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 24]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 32]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 40]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 48]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 56]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 64]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 72]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 80]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 88]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 96]} color={"grey"} />
      </group>
      <group position={[85, 0, 0]}>
        <Row position={[0, 0, 0]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 8]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 16]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 24]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 32]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 40]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 48]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 56]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 64]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 72]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 80]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 88]} color={"grey"} />
        <Row position={[0, 0, 96]} color={"grey"} />
      </group>
    </group>
  );
}


I have more than 10 zones for that reason , I need some way of creating objects
I tried to use InstancedMesh for reducing the freezing because of object amount but anyway I got this freezing in my app

Well, what do your browser's performance inspector's recordings look like when it's "freezing"?

i will upload screenshot about it   https://ibb.co/pztXJJS

You will need to zoom in a bit to see what's taking up time...

https://ibb.co/vXZcZVy     is that what you asked ?

TBH, I'm asking you to interpret the results yourself – it's hard to say anything from just an image. In any case, I put the components you show here in a simple test app, and it's running at 120 FPS or so for me and the performance tab doesn't look anything like yours, so there's something else going on you're not showing us.

In any case, using drei's <Merged> for the shelf meshes might help a lot.

When I duplicate the <S112> group some 15 times, and look at all of the shelves and boxes, it does slow down. I get a significant performance increase from simply React.memo()ing the component that renders it.

As usual, the trick to making something faster is making it do less work.
An example that renders 20 copies of <S112> renders much faster with a couple of changes:

You call generateBoxPositions() again for every render of Shelf – memoize the result (or assign it to a global, as below). Similarly, instead of new Array(5) for an array of 5 things, just write it out...
Compute the shelf and box geometries, as well as the materials only once and reuse them. (See the docs.) This saves a lot on WebGL draw calls.
Use drei's <Instances> and <Instance> to render the repeated boxes on each shelf to coalesce them into a single draw call too.

function generateBoxPositions() {
  const positions: [number, number, number][] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      positions.push([-4 + j * 2, i * 1.5 + 0.5, 0]); // Adjust position
    }
  }
  return positions;
}

const boxPositions = generateBoxPositions();

const materialsByColor = {};
function getMaterialWithColor(color) {
  if (!materialsByColor[color]) {
    materialsByColor[color] = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color });
  }
  return materialsByColor[color];
}

const brownMaterial = getMaterialWithColor("brown");
const itemBoxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1.5, 1, 1);
const shelfLongGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(10, 0.1, 2);
const shelfEndGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.2, 7, 2);

function Shelf({ position, color }) {
  const shelfMat = getMaterialWithColor(color);
  return (
    <group position={position}>
      {[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].map((i) => (
        <mesh
          key={i}
          position={[0, i * 1.5, 0]}
          material={shelfMat}
          geometry={shelfLongGeometry}
        />
      ))}
      {[0, 1].map((i) => (
        <mesh
          key={i}
          position={[i === 0 ? -4.8 : 4.8, 3, 0]}
          material={shelfMat}
          geometry={shelfEndGeometry}
        />
      ))}
      <Instances geometry={itemBoxGeometry} material={brownMaterial}>
        {boxPositions.map((pos, index) => (
          <Instance key={index} position={pos} />
        ))}
      </Instances>
    </group>
  );
}

